# Where clause in RDLC reporting

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

```
=iif(Fields!SubjectCode.Value=Parameters!SubjectCode.Value,Fields!SpAbsentCount.Value,0)
```

I have a Main Report and a sub report

SubjectCode parameter is passed to the subreport from the main report

for each subject code sub report is generated. based on the subject code I need to select a single value(SpAbsentCount) to display on the sub report

something like select... from... where SubectCode=@SubjectCode

I tried the above expression but it doesn't work

Comment: What does it end up showing? Just 0?

Comment: @mindparse first subreport shows the correct value, rest shows 0

Comment: What is the value of Parameters!SubjectCode.Value? Also, where are you putting that expression? Can you post a screenshot of where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without knowing the data and setup of your report, but one guess I have is that you have a whole set of values, and your IIF expression winds up looking at only the first row of values. Try creating a tablix or list that filters on the SubjectCode, then using your code.